# How to make pyes search method to return the keys of the found documents?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I have a question about pyes (Python API of the ElasticSearch).

Is it possible to make the search method to return the keys of the found documents?

The code I use:

```
import pyes
conn = pyes.ES('localhost:9200')
q = pyes.StringQuery("november rain", default_operator="AND")
result = conn.search(query=q, indices=[index])
for r in result:
    print r
```

**Result:** found **documents**, without the key (_id field) that I saved the document with.

The question is **how to return the _id keys?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All results in a `ResultSet` are just `ElasticSearchModel` objects. So you can access the `_id` attribute via the `_meta` DotDict like this

```
r._meta.id
```

`_meta` also contains some other useful information:

```
(Pdb) pp res._meta
{'connection': <pyes.es.ES object at 0x8268ecc>,
 u'id': u'2',
 u'index': u'twitter',
 'parent': None,
 u'score': 0.095891505000000002,
 u'type': u'tweet'}
```

See the documentation on [models](http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/models.html#pyes-models) and [result sets](http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/resultset.html#pyes-resultset) for more details.